# How to convert longblob to readable format

Tags: mysql, ansible, ara

I'm using ara for my ansible project to stock playbook output into database (Mysql).
Some Tables are not readable i would like to know how to convert that in order to develop a php page to display thos values:

here's my table description :

```
mysql> desc data;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id          | varchar(36)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| playbook_id | varchar(36)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| key         | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| value       | longblob     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| type        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

as you see the value column is longblob so the output is not clear:

```
mysql> select value from data;
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| value                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| xœmŽË
ƒ0å"¸kMÄGÍ¾àÊU«@±5b &!7
ýû&R
¥Åp3Ì$§'fåc’Â!{©” ¸x™ÁQ¢Í"¦ÐíùB©`€‹ãš
                                           b%so­päjTëÌb÷j½9c<×ð_yÑ”»2øaó¢Ipíg;âOºd¬Û€~˜†xÆi~_À¡Ï¿[M“u¼`‘ó*´îáWòìI=N                                                                                                                                                     |
| xœmŽË
ƒ0å"¸³&â£f_påªU Ø1““R
¥Åp3Ì$Çæ0
˜ä}–Â!©” 8{™ÃA¢Í#¦Ð©`€«ãšŒb#Ë`­päbTçÌjwj»:c<×ð_EÙTY|ŸUÁË6Âµ_ì„?éŠ±þôÃ4Äã0ÎËûŽCñÝjë˜lšà%‹\Ô¡u
                                                                                                  ¿’'ìÂ=O
```

i try to convert those data to use UTF-8 but it gives me null:

```
SELECT CONVERT(value USING utf8) FROM data;
+---------------------------+
| CONVERT(value USING utf8) |
+---------------------------+
| NULL                      |
| NULL                      |
| NULL                      |
| NULL                      |
| NULL                      |
| NULL                      |
| NULL                      |
| NULL                      |
| NULL                      |
| NULL                      |
| NULL                      |
| NULL                      |
| NULL                      |
| NULL                      |
| NULL                      |
| NULL                      |
| NULL                      |
+---------------------------+
17 rows in set, 18 warnings (0,00 sec)
```

Comment: I don't know ara but the value is most likely some binary serialized object

Comment: You can't convert blobs to text if you have no idea what's inside - you can't just "guess" and stick utf8 in front of it. Also, if something is saved as a long binary object, it means there was a reason for it. Did you design this database model?

Comment: I'm not the DB designer

Answer (score 0):

I helped design some of those models :) (although I am no longer an active developer on the project).

Have you considered just using the Ara web interface as the UI for this data? It's generally a bad idea to poke directly at the database like this because it typically hasn't been designed as a stable API: there's an excellent chance that some future update will break your code, because the assumption is that only ARA is accessing the database.

In any case:

In order to save space, many of the values stored in the database are compressed using Python's `zlib.compress` method. This is handled by the [CompressedData](https://github.com/ansible-community/ara/blob/master/ara/models.py#L126) type, which looks like this:

```
class CompressedData(types.TypeDecorator):
    """
    Implements a new sqlalchemy column type that automatically serializes
    and compresses data when writing it to the database and decompresses
    the data when reading it.
    http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/custom_types.html
    """
    impl = types.LargeBinary

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        return zlib.compress(encodeutils.to_utf8(jsonutils.dumps(value)))

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        if value is not None:
            return jsonutils.loads(zlib.decompress(value))
        else:
            return value

    def copy(self, **kwargs):
        return CompressedData(self.impl.length)
```

You will need to use the `zlib.decompress` method -- or the `php` equivalent -- to read those values. I am not a PHP developer, but it looks as if PHP as a [zlib module](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.zlib.php).